# This is a question about reading a binary file

Tags: c++, fstream

There is a binary file that stores 2 million 'Player' class object information.

I want to open the file in Visual Studio, read the information, and insert it into the members of the 'Player' class object in vector that I created.

This is the configuration of the Player class.

```
class Player {
    std::string name;   
    int score;          
    int id;             
    size_t num;         // Size of bytes obtained in the free store
    char* p;            // Start address of free memory
};
```

Binary files were saved by this way.

```
void Player::write( std::ostream& os ) {
       os.write((char*)this, sizeof(Player));
       os.write((char*)p, num);
}
```

I tried with this way.
I used **Release** mode.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


class Player {
    std::string name;       
    int score;          
    int id;             
    size_t num;         
    char* p;    
public:
    void printElements()
    {
        std::cout << "name:" << name << ", "
            << "id:" << id << ", "
            << "score:" << score << ", "
            << "num:" << num << std::endl;
    }   
};
int main() {
    std::ifstream infile("file", std::ifstream::binary);

    std::vector<Player> v;
    v.reserve(2'000'000);
    Player* player = new Player;
    char* q = new char;

    for (int i = 0; i < v.capacity(); i++) {
        infile.read((char*)player, sizeof(Player));
        infile.read((char*)q, sizeof(q));
        v.push_back(*player);
        v.at(i).printElements();
    }

    delete player;
    delete q;
}
```

**This is what I wanted.**

```
name:jhxubuhgldh    , id:476109 , score:435832437, num:969
name:pmemwohbgqwwg  , id:789387 , score:257570203, num:481
name:zzirtu         , id:1477302, score:172025616, num:37
name:nxkrhdujq      , id:4481   , score:461657936, num:258
name:benijj         , id:1867600, score:39352766, num:658
name:wvukciloi      , id:734835 , score:416874932, num:605
name:fisp           , id:1611284, score:194548462, num:734
name:xfjvbgocgnvgfr , id:995733 , score:181002072, num:834
name:rmg            , id:911109 , score:153943559, num:415
...
```

However, I couldn't read more than one object's information with my code.
I thought it was a problem caused by not being able to read the contents of char*p clearly, and I tried many things, but I couldn't find the answer myself.How can I read the binary file perfectly?
Please let me know if there is anything lacking in the question.

Comment: You can't use `read` and `write` on objects that are using dynamic allocation.  You will need to look into serialization.

Comment: `std::string` is too complicated to write to a file with `write`.  `write` doesn't know what you want done with the pointers inside the `string`; it simply writes the addresses to the file. These addresses are useless to you if not outright fatal. You want to write the data AT the relevant pointers to the file.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully understand about serialization. Does that mean I have to modify the names of the class members' data types?

Comment: In any case, don't be lazy and create a [mcve] which creates a file and reads from it. In this way we can provide a fix for the `write` and `read` functions. If you want to try yourself, each member of Player must be written independently with a defined format: strings could be preceded by the number of characters (32 bit limit is ok?), `int` should be defined to be 32 bits, `size_t` could be 32 or 64 bits (you choose). Basically you must define your binary format. Remember that between member variables there may be alignment padding added by the compiler, which could change at each version.

Comment: `infile.read((char*)player, sizeof(Player));`  You can't just photocopy a Player, it's a non-trivial class, (because of the std::string it contains) and can't be copied with memcpy, for example.  See [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7189821/1563833) regarding **Trivial classes**.